# Could I restrict to 1 element the Backpack CRUD?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I would like to have only 1 element to CRUD (edit, update and create). How can I restrict to max 1 element in database ?

Ex : you have app settings and you do not need several records but only one.

How can we do ?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `ListOperationTrait` from the CrudController and [create a custom operation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations#creating-a-new-operation-with-no-interface), say `RedirectOperationTrait`. That operation:

- would looks like the `ListOperationTrait` (have the same route)
- would not show anything to the user, just redirect to the correct URL (create/update);